# Where to get the driver for these unusual Balthaup screws?

Tags: fastener, screwdriver

These unusual large screws are from a Balthaup (Germany) dining table,

[image]

(My child's "CSI credit card" there for scale :) )

[image]

The table's around 12? yrs old.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a *[pin wrench](http://www.sears.com/cr-laurence-crl-adjustable-spanner-wrench/p-SPM6442245108?plpSellerId=DKHardware&prdNo=1&blockNo=1&blockType=G1)* (or *pin spanner*).

[image: pin wrench]

They come in fixed and adjustable types.

> Images and links are illustrative only, not an endorsement of goods or sources.

Comment: I agree, in the past I have even made one drilling the 2 holes and pressing pins in a piece of bar stock.

Comment: @Fattie There are many versions and sources online.

Comment: fantastic stuff.  I notice the ones that have a number of size pins, are quite expensive.  I'll first try exactly the model pictured.  Cheers!

Comment: It turns out this *exact model* is made for the Balthaup fittings.  Excellent!

Answer (score 1):

The Bolts are Spanner Bolts and the tool is generally referred to as a spanner wrench.

TC-Equipment-Variable-Spanner-OTC-526908-7

[image: Spanner Wrench]

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, thanks Ken.  "spanner bolts" - "spanner wrench".  I saw that very kit for sale, it's a bit expensive.  I'm going to try first one of the simple fixed ones which are only a few $$.  Thanks - awesome.

Comment: It would appear these are often used for things like pulleys.

Answer (score 1):

Fantastic stuff - for the hordes of googlers also needing the spanner for this Balthaup table attachments:

indeed the "CRL pin spanner" is perfect. **The pin size is exactly correct.**

The pitch you can vary, but I was concerned the pin size itself may be wrong. if you have to buy a pin spanner with **exchangeable pins**, to cover all metric/imperial pin sizes, the only sets I found were 100+ bucks.

Fortunately this CR Laurence model which is only 10-20 bucks is perfect.

[image]

Great stuff.

it appears to be known as a "spanner for Top Roller" in some markets.

[image]

Thanks, internet