# What's the spanner called for these "four side notch" collars/bolts?

Tags: tools, bolts

Notice this thing,

[image]

for a 30mm ...

[image]

What is the tool to tighten that properly?

It would seem to be best if it was a long tube-like thing you slid down from the top and tightened, but, maybe there's a thing that grabs it from the side?

(And, what's that type of bolt known as?!)

Comment: Interestingly I only learned what a pin wrench is thanks to this fantastic site!  https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/136621/79954  .  But this thing is different, a pin wrench does not do the job it seems.

Comment: If I only have to do it a couple times the appropriate tools are a vise, a hammer, and two screwdrivers or sturdy metal rods.

Comment: Right!  No, it needs to be done repeatedly ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hook wrench (as used on bicycles)

https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16291/what-tool-is-needed-to-adjust-this-headset-on-a-childrens-bike

[image]

Comment: I have adjustable or jointed ones also that allows for a larger range of nuts , I thought the name was broke spanner, but that's just a Nick name we use at work.

Comment: A hook wrench !!  fantastic !

Comment: "broke spanner" great name :)

Comment: @Jasen thanks again. My "thing" there is a "30mm" one.  Meaning the exact diameter of the **"pole"** is 30mm.  I guess then the outside diameter of the four-notch bolt is perhaps 35-40 mm.  (I'll measure it.)  In fact, do you reckon I need a "30" size hook wrench, or do I need a "40" size hook wrench ?!  I wonder how they measure that?  Again thanks!

Comment: not my field of expertise, but I would immagine it's by the outer diameter of the ring-nut so 40.

Answer (score 3):

It is called a four pin spanner socket. Finding one the correct size may be difficult. I would try a local tool supplier with a liberal return policy so if you select the wrong one you can exchange it. There are standard sizes but I have run into some specialty sizes (correct diameter but wrong pin size) issues. If you are handy with a die grinder you can modify a standard socket by cutting notches it. I have also fabricated one from a standard socket by welding pieces of key stock to the outside of the socket.

Comment: he has the nut detached in image one, he could take it in to the shop.